# A beautiful trigger issue. Flawed logic? Updating Orderheader when orderlines are complete

Tags: oracle, trigger

THe bussiness rule is as such: The orderlines must be updated with a date stamp when all the related orderlines are marked as 'Y' denoting a completed order line.

THe trigger thus far is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orderComplete
after update ON orderline
DECLARE 
orderId NUMBER;
ordersNotDone NUMBER;
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(Orderline_fulfilled), order_id INTO ordersNotDone, orderId
    FROM orderHeader
    JOIN orderline ON
    orderHeader.Order_id = orderLine.Orderline_order
    WHERE Order_id = orderline_order
    AND orderline_fulfilled = 'N'
    GROUP BY order_id;

    if ordersNotDone = 0
    then
        UPDATE orderHeader
        set ORDER_COMPLETED = sysdate
        WHERE order_id = orderId;
    end if;

END;
```

Upon an update of the order line, an 'no data found' is returned- is this sugesting the orderId variable is not returning data? The queries do work, however, when taken out of the trigger and ran independently.

Answer (score 1):

- Your trigger checks **all** orderlines for completeness even when only one is updated. You should use the :NEW table prefix to filter the currently updated record.
- There is no need to include the table `orderHeader` while counting
- There is no need for a group-by

Try the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orderComplete
   AFTER UPDATE ON orderline
 FOR EACH ROW -- Added after comment by a1ex07 
 DECLARE ordersNotDone NUMBER;
 BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(Orderline_fulfilled)
      INTO ordersNotDone
      FROM orderline
     WHERE orderline_order = :NEW.orderline_order
       AND orderline_fulfilled = 'N';

    IF ordersNotDone = 0
    THEN
        UPDATE orderHeader
        SET order_completed = sysdate
        WHERE order_id = NEW:orderline_order;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: There is no way he can use `NEW` or `OLD` in statement-level trigger. If you want to access `NEW/OLD` it must be `FOR EACH ROW` trigger.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that. So is there a reason he show not add the `FOR EACH ROW`?

Comment: Surely, your solution will work for row-level trigger. I just pointed out that OP uses statement-level trigger (no idea why, maybe he has some reasons) ; in this case you cannot refer `NEW` or `OLD`

Answer (score 0):

Jeff's advice is all good <sup>+1</sup>, but I would take it a few steps further.  The `UPDATE` and the `SELECT` can be combined into one statement and that statement can be moved out of the trigger into the code block (probably should be a seperate procedure) that marks an orderline with 'Y'.  Something like this:

```
UPDATE OrderLine SET OrderLine_Fullfilled = 'N' WHERE Order_Id = vOrderId AND ... ;

UPDATE OrderHeader SET Order_Completed = sysdate WHERE Order_Id = vOrderId
AND NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM OrderLine WHERE Order_Id = vOrderId AND OrderLine_Fullfilled = 'N');
```

Assuming most of your orders are complete, if you create a function based index on DECODE(OrderLine_Fullfilled,'N',Order_Id,NULL) then you could use the following faster query:

```
UPDATE OrderHeader SET Order_Completed = sysdate WHERE Order_Id = vOrderId
AND NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM OrderLine WHERE DECODE(OrderLine_Fullfilled,'N',Order_Id,NULL)=vOrderId);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your trigger to be as it is (statement trigger), you can do

```
UPDATE (
SELECT a.ORDER_COMPLETED, a.Order_id
FROM orderHeader a
WHERE NOT EXIST (
  SELECT 1 FROM OrderLine b WHERE a.Order_Id = b.Orderline_order AND   
  b.OrderLine_Fullfilled = 'N')b
)c
SET c.ORDER_COMPLETED = 'N'
```